# How can i make it so that different views shows based on which map annotation is clicked?

Tags: swiftui, mapkit

I am trying to make it so that different views shows based on which map annotation is clicked. I am using navigationView and have not been able to make the destination conditional.

```
import MapKit
import SwiftUI
    
struct Location: Identifiable {
let id = UUID() 
let name: String 
let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D 
let symbol: String
    } 
struct ContentView: View {
        @State private var mapRegion = MKCoordinateRegion (center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.5, longitude: -0.12), span: MKCoordinateSpan (latitudeDelta: 0.2, longitudeDelta: 0.2))
let locations = [ Location (name: "Buckingham Palace", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:                                      
    51.508, longitude: -0.076),symbol: "house"), Location(name: "Tower of London", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 57.919, longitude: 12.577), symbol: "key")
        ]
var body: some View { 
NavigationView { 
Map(coordinateRegion: $mapRegion, annotationItems: locations) { location in MapAnnotation(coordinate: location.coordinate) {
    
    NavigationLink ( destination:  if location.symbol == "house"{  View2()} else {View3()}
                    }) { 
    ZStack{
     Circle()
      .frame(width: 35, height: 35)
      .foregroundColor(.orange) 
    Image(systemName: location.symbol)
    .foregroundColor(.white)
                        }
    
    
                }
                }
                .onAppear {
     MKMapView.appearance().mapType = .satellite
                }
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            }
            .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
    
        }
    
    
    }
    
    struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider { static var previews: some View { ContentView()
            }
    
        }
```

I have tried with an if statement in the navigationlink() but it does not work.

Comment: Please fix your code formatting so it's readable.

Comment: It should be more readable now. Please tell me if something still is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this different approach, using a `NavigationStack`, instead of the deprecated NavigationView, a `Button` and a `switch`
in `navigationDestination`. Works well for me.

```
struct Location: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    let symbol: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var mapRegion = MKCoordinateRegion (center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.5, longitude: -0.12), span: MKCoordinateSpan (latitudeDelta: 0.2, longitudeDelta: 0.2))
    
    let locations = [
        Location(name: "Buckingham Palace", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.501, longitude: -0.141), symbol: "house"),
        Location(name: "Tower of London", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.508, longitude: -0.076), symbol: "key")
    ]
    
    @State private var path = NavigationPath()  // <-- here
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) { // <-- here
            Map(coordinateRegion: $mapRegion, annotationItems: locations) { location in MapAnnotation(coordinate: location.coordinate) {
                Button(action: { path.append(location.symbol) }) {  // <-- here
                    ZStack {
                        Circle().frame(width: 55, height: 55).foregroundColor(.orange)
                        Image(systemName: location.symbol).foregroundColor(.white)
                    }
                }
            }
            }.onAppear {
                MKMapView.appearance().mapType = .satellite
            }
            .ignoresSafeArea()
            .navigationDestination(for: String.self) { val in  // <-- here
                switch val {
                    case "house": View2()
                    case "key": View3()
                    default: View1()
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
    }

}

struct View1: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("View1")
    }
}

struct View2: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("View2")
    }
}

struct View3: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("View3")
    }
}
```

Comment: In my iOS 17 only app, there's an obvious hangs/latency when I select one of my tabbar items to open up the View as a navigation view from my main view which has a Map that's showing around 10 annotation items. 

The problem I encountered is indeed strange. Visible region of the Map shows only the Annotations and as Annotations shown and then tapping on tab button to show first view of navigation view there's an obvious latency but when change the Map visible region to area without Annotations, navigation view smoothly opens up.